# "The type or namespace name could not be found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I use MSBuild Version 14.0.

Following the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx), I defined my own `Build` task like this:

```
<Target Name="Build" 
        Inputs="@(Compile)"
        Outputs="MyLibrary.dll">

        <Csc 
            Sources="@(Compile)"
            Resources="@(EmbeddedResource)" 
            References="@(Reference);@(ProjectReference)" 
            OutputAssembly="MyLibrary.dll"/>
</Target>
```

In one of my `ItemGroup`s, I have a list of project references, e.g.:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\ProjectReference1.csproj">
  <Project>{A3DBEB8E-997D-4F88-A56C-B45647EB5C29}</Project>
  <Name>ProjectReference1</Name>
  <Private>False</Private>
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="..\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\ProjectReference2.csproj">
  <Project>{8bd1049a-afe2-44c1-8ecc-020000ec13ab}</Project>
  <Name>ProjectReference2</Name>
  <Private>False</Private>
</ProjectReference>
```

When I ran the command `MSBuild.exe C:\Workspaces\MyProject.csproj /t:build`, I saw a long list of error messages, like the following:

```
File1.cs(27,79): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Type1' could no
t be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Workspaces\MyProject.csproj]
```

`Type1` is defined in one of the project references included in my `.csproj` file.

Why are those errors thrown by MSBuild even though I have specified that the `References` field in my `CSC` task should include project references? What should I do to ensure that my project builds successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the Build Target to just invoke Csc. The Csc task is just a wrapper around csc.exe, it's Reference attribute is csc.exe's [/reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option) option which expects assemblies: a ProjectReference to an msbuild file doesn't mean anything to it. You have to build those projects first, and pass their output assemblies to the Reference attribute. Which is basically what a proper project file as created by Visual Studio does for you automatically (it builds ProjectReferences first - if out of date -, figures out what the output assemblies are, adds it to the References), so I'd suggest you use that as a starting point.